# Add urls to a list via Automator

Tags: macos, safari, automator, google-chrome

What is the simplest way to append a list of urls with a selected URL when browsing either chrome or safari. I tried to do this with automator and it was easy to achieve by creating a service with a **Write Text to File** action (from an add on package). But it does not add a new line after each entry. It doesn't even write a space after an entry. So you end up with a file like

```
http://example./Ahttp://example.com/Bhttp://example.com/Chttp://example.com/Dhttp://example.com/Ehttp://example.com/F
```

My next attempt to use a **Split Text** action somehow resulted in 100 new files being created, each containing a single URL. **`(>_<)`**

What I'm trying to achieve is:

- Select a URL in the browser's (chrome or safari) address bar
- Right click the highlighted URL to get to the services menu
- Click on the created service (we'll call it **Add to List**)
- Add the selected URL to text file in the Home folder followed by a new line.

The desired output being:

```
http://example.com/A
http://example.com/B
http://example.com/C
http://example.com/D
http://example.com/E
http://example.com/F
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Automator workflow you have so far?

Comment: I should have kept asking the duck before submitting the question. I think I solved it with applescript but I'd be happy to post screen shots of the previous workflow and / or the current applescript solution.

Comment: Great! Just answer your own question with the solution you've found then, and accept it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an effective solution. A single Automator **Run AppleScript** action with the following script:

```
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set my_list to "/Users/username/Documents/URL_list.txt"
tell application "Google_Chrome" to set new_items to (get the URL of the active tab in window 1) as string
do shell script "echo  " & quoted form of new_items & " >>  " & quoted form of my_list

display dialog new_items with title "Added to the list"
```

- Save as a service
- Service receives selected **URLs**
- Input is **only URLs** (probably doesn't matter)
- Tested and working in both Safari and Google Chrome

  - If using Safari change the `get the URL of the active tab in window 1` to `get the URL of the current tab in window 1`. Just to clarify: use **`active tab`** for Chrome and use **`current tab`** for Safari.
  - If you have several windows and tabs open and want to grab every URL to populate a list: `tell application "Google_Chrome" to set new_items to (get the URL of the tabs in every window) as string`

[image]